# What is the "with_front" rewrite key?

Tags: functions

I have the following line in a register_post_type function:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Newsletters', 'with_front' => false),
```

I understand what the line does in general (adds "newsletters" to the slug) but I don't specifically understand what the 'with_front' part does. I have to admit, I don't really have a problem that needs solving, but I'm suddenly curious....

Comment: I'm not sure why you would rename the slug if you don't plan on using it, but  the slug is typically lowercase as it's the url.

Comment: I don't remember much from '12 so I don't have much follow-up. It was using the slug for sure... I just wasn't understanding what it was doing with it. I hate implementing code that I don't understand the mechanics of.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) ...

> Should the permastruct be prepended with the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is `/blog/`, then your links will be: false->`/news/`, true->`/blog/news/`). Defaults to true

Comment: Thanks. I can never find anything directly on the Codex, and using web search was getting me nowhere!

Comment: I can always find everything with OLD Codex , but new DevelopersCodex seems poor.

Comment: +1 The old codex is way better even to this day.  It's easier to read, more documentation on it, better examples and interpretation is way better.  Not to mention easier on the eyes, as the new codex just gives a red flag to me on the eyes!