# True or F False Setting of 'with_front' Parameter of Rewrite Is returning Exact Same result

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, rewrite-rules

Setting the `'with_front'` to `true` or `false` in my Custom Taxonomy is landing to the exact same urls as

```
http://localhost:8080/wp/commercial-services/action/
http://localhost:8080/wp/commercial-services/action/
```

I have the `rewrite` rule as

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'commercial-services','with_front' => false),
```

and also I changed it to

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'commercial-services','with_front' => true),
```

but as I said it is landing it exact same URLs, so can you please let me know what is the point of using this property? I also flushed the WP every time after changing the true or false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "with\_front" rewrite key?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53190/what-is-the-with-front-rewrite-key)

Comment: It's likely because your permalink structure doesn't have a *static* "front"/base (other than `/`).